# Display the textbox when i select dropdown value

Tags: jquery

I have one dropdown list and textboxes. Initially textboxes are hide. when i select the value in drop down list, textboxes will be show

```
    <select class="dropdown">
    <option>Choose your location</option>
    <option>Bangalore</option>
    <option>Delhi NCR</option>
    <option>Mumbai</option>
    <option>Chennai</option>
    <option>Pune</option>
    <option>Kilkatta</option>
</select>

    <input type="text"  name="name" class="textbox ph_textbox">    
    <input type="text"  name="phone"  class="textbox ph_textbox">    
    <input type="text"  name="email"class="textbox ph_textbox">
```

jquery

```
 $("#select").change(function(e){
      $(".ph_textbox").show();  
    });
```

Comment: There's an error in code, use $("select") instead of  $("#select")

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you've included jQuery properly.

2) Add `id="select"` to your `select`.

3) Place your code after adding jQuery library and inside DOM ready handler:

```
$(function() {
    $("#select").change(function (e) {
        $(".ph_textbox").show();
    });
});
```

and it should works.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eYuRp/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=text]').hide();
$("select").change(function(e){
      $(".ph_textbox").show();  
    });
```

Use the above code. # is meant to select ids. Just to match elemnts, just the name is enough.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/gPb5p/